# Proguard and Android :(

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

I am trying to run Proguard on my Android app and running into issues.

I am using SpongyCastle jar (copy and past of full bouncy castle with package renamed so it does not conflict with androids bouncy castle built in version)

When running proguard I see the following

How do I fix this? Add rt.jar to my libs?

The whole point of proguard is to shrink the code, but I keep adding jars to get around these issues where proguard complains it cannot find a class! Am I missing something?

```
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.SearchControls
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.SearchControls
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.SearchControls
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.SearchControls
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.SearchControls
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.DirContext
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.NamingEnumeration
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.NamingEnumeration
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.SearchResult
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.SearchResult
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.Attributes
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.Attribute
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.Attribute
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.NamingEnumeration
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.DirContext
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.NamingException
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.DirContext
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.NamingEnumeration
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.Attributes
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.DirContext
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.DirContext
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.SearchResult
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.NamingEnumeration
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.SearchControls
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.NamingEnumeration
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.NamingException
[proguard] Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.DirContext
[proguard] Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper'
[proguard] Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService'
[proguard] Note: there were 2 references to unknown classes.
[proguard]       You should check your configuration for typos.
[proguard] Warning: there were 57 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[proguard]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars'),
[proguard]          or perhaps the '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses' option.

UILD FAILED
:\AndroidSDK\android-sdk_r12-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:713: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

**Update**

```
ANT Script
```

I used `android update project --path .` to generate the build.xml as the project was created sometime ago and I haven't made any changes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project name="RootActivity" default="help">
        <loadproperties srcFile="local.properties" />
        <property file="ant.properties" />
        <loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />
        <fail message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project'" unless="sdk.dir" />
        <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
    </project>
```

Comment: Can you post the part of your ant script responsible?  This seems like a problem with importing the standard java libraries in android...

Comment: I used android update project --path . to generate the build.xml as the project was created sometime ago and I haven't made any changes 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="RootActivity" default="help">

    <loadproperties srcFile="local.properties" />

    <property file="ant.properties" />

    <loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />

    <fail
            message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project'"
            unless="sdk.dir"
    />

    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />

</project>

Comment: There is a related [issue #27612](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27612).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a need to add rt.jar to your libs. You need to make sure you are referencing it properly in your proguard script.  Take a look [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) for an example. This line in section 2 is the money maker:

```
-libraryjars ${java.home}/lib/rt.jar
```

Although, that syntax changes if you use the xml notation for proguard. If you post the part of the ant script that is responsible I can try to be of more assistance. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 20):

Add the following, `-dontwarn javax.naming.**` , to your Proguard configuration.

They are just warnings, and ignoring them shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: This is the officially recommended solution. The naming package is missing on Android, but apparently this is not causing any problems.

Comment: For others having the same issue but with a gradle-based build (android studio) - check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18481752/1041533 and make sure to include both proguard files correctly! The default one and yours with above statements in it